# Cannot signin to pinterest app through postman to request tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, pinterest

I am trying to get request token of my pinterest app through postman. But google is not allowing to sign me in to the app. Below is the screenshot:
[image]

Please help me with this. I'm stuck.